# Is it possible to put condition over column in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to  execute the below command.

I have a table for example `employee_master` and the fields are 
`Name, Age, address, telephone, email,..` rest "xyz" Column will be generated in run-time.

I am trying to fetch all `"xyz"` fields of unknown columns but i want only `name, address, age` of known coloumns

```
select * fields 
from table/view 
where column name  <> "telephone" 
  and column name <> "email".
```

is it possible in mysql?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: try to set only column in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all column xyz with the following query:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` from information_schema.columns where `TABLE_NAME` = "employee_master" AND `COLUMN_NAME` NOT IN ("telephone","email");
```

Then use the result to make the final select of all field in column xyz.

Comment: Sir, i simply want to exclude column from select query which i dont want. but the problem is i dont know the exact columns(because it is generated in runtime in my create view script) except some.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```
select `name`, `address`, `age`, `xyz`  
from employee_master
```

Comment: @Spider-TheWebMaker Wow, this is just quite simple problem which has been more complicated by your words.

Comment: sir.. but the problem is that i dont know what will be name of that "x","y","z" columns they may be "a","c","d".

Comment: And when do you know this "xyz" is what?

Comment: when it displays the result. coz the view is generating by php script on runtime.

Comment: So why don't you just `select *`, then choose the column what you need to use?

Answer (score -1):

yes ofcourse it is possible. but you have to use single quote instead of double quotes for string

select * from table/view where column ='value'